# Resharper error running nunit tests for solution in Any CPU mode

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper, resharper-2016

I'm having trouble running resharper tests for my solution when targeting Any CPU. The error I'm getting is

> ERROR System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///D:_dist\path\to\my\bin\folder\JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestRunner.nUnit30.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName,
>   String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder,
>   Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String
>   assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue,
>   AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile) at
>   JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestRunner.nUnit.NUnitTaskRunner.SetupRunnerAssembly(NUnitVersion
>   nUnitVersion) at
>   JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestRunner.nUnit.NUnitTaskRunner.SetUpNUnitRunner(NUnitVersion
>   version, String nUnitInstallDir) at
>   JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestRunner.nUnit.NUnitTaskRunner.RunTestsInAssemblies(List`1
>   assemblies, NUnitTestAssemblySetTask assemblySetTask, Boolean
>   useAddins, NUnitVersion nUnitVersion) at
>   JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestRunner.nUnit.NUnitTaskRunner.ExecuteRecursive(TaskExecutionNode
>   node) at
>   JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunnerFramework.StartupTaskRunnerHost.Execute(TaskExecutionNode
>   node) at
>   JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunnerFramework.StartupTaskRunnerHost.ExecuteNodes(IEnumerable`1
>   nodes) at
>   JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunnerFramework.TasksPacketHandler.ThreadProc(TaskRunnerProxy
>   proxy, IEnumerable`1 packets, AssemblyLoader loader)

When I turn the solution into x86, the tests run (but because these tests run fine for others with Resharper, I can't just go and create an x86 configuration in the solution).

Does anyone know what the issue is?  I'm running VS2015, Resharper 2016.3.2, and the solution is a c#/asp.net mvc solution, with a Service Fabric microservice (the other reason I'd rather not resort to having to switch to x86 to run tests).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone runs into this, the error should push you to the thought of trying to figure out why it's trying to load ReSharper dlls from your projects bin folder.

It looks like ReSharper uses `System.Environment.CurrentDirectory` to get its dlls, so when someone changed the value during one of the tests, it broke subsequent ones when ReSharper needed to access the nunit runner.